# How to get text formatting information from HSLFSlideShow

Tags: java, android, apache-poi, text-formatting

I am using Apache POI's `HSLFSlideShow`and extracting the paragraphs individually using:

`String paragraph = currentSlide.getTextParagraphs().get(i).toString();`

However I am unable to figure out how to extract formatting information, such as bold, italic, text size and typeface.

I did come across the `CharacterRun`, which seems to have the features I need, however it does not seem to be applicable to `HSLFSlideShow` (unless I'm using it wrong).

My overall task can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50587832/how-do-you-convert-a-ppt-file-to-html-using-apache-poi).

Comment: What's wrong with the getter methods on [HSLFTextParagraph](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hslf/usermodel/HSLFTextParagraph.html) like [getFontSize](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hslf/usermodel/HSLFTextParagraph.html#getDefaultFontSize--) and friends?

Comment: From what I can see, it doesn't seem to support more options other than size. Like I mentioned above, I am especially interested in bold or italic, typeface and I'll add colour in now, at the very least.